# C++ | How to set an entire 2d Array to O's

Tags: c++

I want to set an entire 2D-Array to O's (not 0's).
My attempt on that was:

```
char field[10][10] = {'O'};
```

But that didn't work and I can't find anything on the internet. The other problem is that I get this Error:

> "Variable i was used without being initialized"

when I'm trying to run the Code below

```
for (int i; i<10; i++) {

            // Creating random bomb spot coordinates
            int bombx;
            int bomby;
            bombx = rand() % 10;
            bomby = rand() % 10;

            //If there is no bomb at that spot, set the spot to an X which resembles bombs
            if (!(field[bombx][bomby] = 'X')) {
                field[bombx][bomby] = 'X';
            }
            //If there already is a bomb at that spot, do i-- so it runs another time through the loop because there need to be 10 bombs
            else if (field[bombx][bomby] = 'X') {
                i--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The `=` is assignment.  It does not do an equality comparison even when used in the context of an `if` predicate expression.

Comment: `std::memset(field, 'O', 10*10)`.

Comment: Rolling a loop doesn't work?

Comment: There are too many problems with the shown code to know even where to start. `=` versus `==`. Clearly uninitialized variable. `int i` does not initialize `i` to anything. So, what exactly is your question regarding that?

Comment: "*i cant find anything on the internet*" - I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @melpomene Haven't you heard of the disease "unable to google"?

Comment: With regard to your first question: which compiler version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo havent initialized i
try writing your for loop as
for(int i="the number u want to start your loop with";i<10;i++)

eg=

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

for initialization of 2d array of field with "o"

the following code

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
field[i][j]='O';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also use `std::fill` if you want and give it address of the 1st element and past the last element for iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char field[10][10];
    std::fill(&field[0][0], &field[9][9] + 1, 'O');

    // test
    std::cout << field[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << field[3][5] << std::endl;
    std::cout << field[9][9] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to declare an array and fill the array with O's. your array declaration syntax is wrong. Correct syntax is below

```
char field[size][size] = {{Value, Value,..,size-1},{Value, Value,..,size-1},..,size-1};
```

For Example:

```
char field[2][2] = {{O,O},{O,O}};
```

And your second error is due to, you didn't initialize the variable when you declare them you must have to give them some value like:

```
int bombx = 0;
int bomby = 0;
```

**I hope this will help you**